# docker webpack compiled files missing when running

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, docker-compose

I'm encountering an issue I'm sure is super apparent to a docker expert but is lost on me.

below is my dockerfile, in which I added a few "ls" so I can review the files that webpack is generating.

The first "ls" is correctly showing

```
Step 8 : RUN ls server/public
 ---> Running in 67bc7ee5f832
bundle.css
bundle.js
index.html
```

but the second ls is not

```
web_1    | index.html
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.2

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm i

COPY . /usr/src/app/

# Build Static Resources
RUN npm run build

# ls here shows correct files
RUN ls server/public

# Bundle app source

ENV NODE_ENV=production

# ls here doesn't show compiled files
CMD ls server/public && npm start

EXPOSE 3000
```

What am I missing? why aren't these bundle.css/js not present in the browser after nodejs is running?

How can I check the directory is copied correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`RUN` defines a step that executes during the `docker build` of your image.

`CMD` defines the default command (or arguments passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` if defined) that's executed when you `docker run` your container.

Note that Docker also caches layers, so if you perform another build, the `RUN ls` will be skipped if Docker finds a resulting image for this exact command on the same previous layer's hash.

To look inside your container, you can run a shell to browse it:

`docker run -it --rm your_image_name /bin/bash`

Since you pass `/bin/bash`, the default `CMD` will be bypassed and only a shell will be launched.

Comment: My issue was I was trying to git pull my repository onto the remote server; build the image there, and then use "docker-compose up" which wasn't working (still not sure I understand why).


Instead now I build the images locally, upload them to docker hub, and pull them on the remote server and run them individually and they work as expected

Comment: Looking back at this, I expect the issue was a volume mount being done in the compose file. Without that file, this is just a guess. @Nachiket, please open a new question with your files, comments aren't a good place for q&a.